# vba create a shape that remains always on top

Tags: vba, powerpoint, z-order

Is possible to create a shape in powerpoint using vba that remains always on top? I try to see the options of shapes(x).zOrder. I choose msoBringToFront but when I create another shape, the new shape is the one that is in top.

I check the events that have powerpoint but there is no event when a shape is created... only when a slide is created. Is there any other way?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj227644%28v=office.15%29.aspx for a list of events. `AfterDragDropOnSlide` should be appropriate. Failing that `WindowSelectionChange` is obviously the fallback option. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231084%28v=office.12%29.aspx for the Ppt 2007 equivalent event. There is no 2007 equivalent to AfterDragDropOnSlide.

Comment: See my example posted below.

Comment: did my suggestions help? If not, why not? Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, then you can try something like:

1) Create a class and add the following example code

```
Private WithEvents mApplication As Application
Private mMyShape As Shape

Public Property Set Application(App As Application)
    Set mApplication = App
End Property
'and Getter if necessary

Public Property Set MyShape(shp As Shape)
    Set mMyShape = shp
End Property
'and Getter if necessary

Private Sub mApplication_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    mMyShape.ZOrder msoBringToFront
End Sub
```

2) Create a standard module and add the following example code.

```
Sub blah()
    Dim c1 As Class1
    Set c1 = New Class1
    Set c1.Application = Application
    Set c1.MyShape = 'your shape
End Sub
```

The above works for Powerpoint 2007 onwards. `AfterDragDropOnSlide` event is possibly more appropriate but was only added in Powerpoint 2013. The event used here will fire every time the selection is changed and so should ensure that your shape is in front nearly all the time.

Event references:
WindowSelectionChange: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231084%28v=office.12%29.aspx